# Part two of Fundamental Thm Problem

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

For some $$g(x)=\int_2^xln(t) \ dt$$

How does one solve for $g'(x)$?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of an integral with respect to the upper bound is equal to the integrand where the integration variable has been replaced with the variable denoting the upper bound. With formulas: $\left[\int_a^x f(t)\,dt\right]' = f(x)$. In other words, $g'(x) = \ln(x)$.

To see why, the definition of derivative gives us
$$
\left[\int_a^x f(t)\,dt\right]' = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_a^{x+h}f(d)\,dt - \int_a^xf(t)\,dt}{h}\\
= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt}{h}
$$
Now, one could go all out and use the definition of the integral (whichever one you're using) to analyse this fraction. But I want to be more intuitive about it, and look at it as area under the graph. We see that if $h$ is very small, then the difference between the area in the numerator and the area of a rectangle that is $h$ wide and $f(x)$ tall is miniscule, and that difference becoms an ever smaller part of the total area as $h$ gets smaller.

In other words, for very small $h$, we have $\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt \approx f(x)\cdot h$. Inserting that into the above limit we get
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x)\cdot h}{h} = f(x)
$$ Using some specific and strict definition of the integral to analyse $\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\,dt$ would help us be more precice and prove that the approximation we inserted is actually strong enough to let us conclude the way we did here, and also help us decide in which pathological edge cases the result is valid (for instance, what happens when $f$ is discontinuous at $x$?). However, the main argument is what I've outlined here.